# Unix if condition error inside for loop

Tags: bash, unix

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the search string"
read str

for i in `ls -ltr | grep $str  > filter123.txt ; awk '{ print $9 }' filter123.txt` ; do

if [ $i != "username_list.txt" || $i != "user_list.txt" ] ; then

else
 rm $i
fi
done
```

I'm a beginner of unix shell scritping, i create above file for delete file based on given string using grep method. while i executing above script file it showing error like "./rm_file.txt: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `else' ". please suggested what's the error in this script.

Comment: Why are you using `grep` and `awk` and a temporary file?  Just do `ls -ltr | awk "/$str/{print \$9}"`  (This will fail if str contains certain characters, but so does `grep $str`)

Comment: Use `[[]]` (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#A.5B_.24foo_.3D_.22bar.22_.5D). Also not sure why you're trying `if !a || !b then nothing else something` instead of the logically equivalent `if a && b then something`.

Answer (score 3):

There are several problems with your code:

1. [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Although it may work much of the time, it will break for certain file names, and there are safer alternatives.
2. Replace `filter123.txt` with another pipe.
3. You can negate the exit status of the condition, so that you don't need an `else` clause.
4. Your `if` condition is always true, since any file name will be unequal to one of the two options. You probably mean to use `&&`.
5. `||` and `&&` are not available inside `[ ... ]`. Either use two `[ ... ]` commands or use `[[ ... ]]`.

Addressing the items above:

```
for i in *$str*; do
    if [[ $i != username_list.txt && $i = user_list.txt ]]; then
        rm "$i"
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

between `then` and `else` there is nothing, if you want do nothing, you can put `:` there

to delete files in current director with certain string in the name, you can use `find`

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the search string: " str

# to exclude "username_list.txt" and "user_list.txt"
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*$str*" -a -not \( -name "username_list.txt" -o -name "user_list.txt" \) | xargs -I'{}' ls {}
```

Answer (score 1):

To use a boolean operator with `[`, you can use one of:

```
if [ "$i" != username_list.txt ] && [ "$i" != user_list.txt ] ; then ...
if [ "$i" != username_list.txt -a "$i" != user_list.txt; then ...
```

But in this case, it is probably cleaner to use a case statment:

```
case "$i" in
username_list.txt|user_list.txt) : ;;
*) rm "$i";;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

It can also be done with `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*$str*" ! -name username_list.txt ! -name user_list.txt -exec rm {} \;
```